# AngularJS: Error when injecting $modal inside a controller that is nested inside of a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

We have a custom directive that generates html around a checkbox. This uses transclusion to inject the contents that are passed within it. It looks something like this:

somecheckbox.js

```
angular.module('namespace.directives')
.directive('someCheckbox', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'directives/checkbox.html';
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true
  }
}]);
```

directives/checkbox.html

```
<label class="styling" ng-transclude>
    ... some other html
</label>
```

We extensively use modals throughout our application and are in the process of converting everything to bootstrap's angular directive. We've created a controller that handles a particular type of modal that appears sporadically throughout out application:

```
angular.module('namespace.controllers').controller('LegalModalController',
       ['$scope', '$modal',
function($scope,   $modal) {
  $scope.showLegalModal = function(title, legalTextLocation) {
    $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'modals/legal.html',
      controller: 'sc.LegalModalInstanceController',
      resolve: {
        modalTitle: function() {
          return title;
        },
        template: function() {
          return eulaTextLocation;
        }
      }
    });
  };
}]);
```

Coming back to the directive piece, there is a case where we need to add a link within the checkbox directive that hooks into the legal controller to pop open a modal window. This is what's being done thus far:

```
<some-checkbox>Click <a href ng-controller="LegalModalController" ng-click="showLegalModal()">here</a> to...</some-checkbox>
```

The problem that we're encountering is that we have been thoroughly unable to inject $modal into the controller without getting the following error:

**Unknown provider: $modalProvider <- $modal**

I've looked everywhere, but I haven't found any others who are in this scenario. Does anyone know what could be the potential root of this problem? This linking works in every case where we are not using a directive.

This is the main.js file that starts up the app:

```
angular.module('namespace.modules.main', ['namespace.core', 'ui.select2', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.sortable', 'infinite-scroll', 'ui.bootstrap']).
config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', '$compileProvider', 
function($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider, $compileProvider) {
    routeProvider = $routeProvider;
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');

    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch = {};
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.patch['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset="UTF-8"';

    // Allow telephone hyperlinks
    $compileProvider.urlSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|mailto|tel):/);

}]).run(
         ['$rootScope', '$location', '$timeout', '$window', '$route'
  function($rootScope,   $location,   $timeout,   $window,   $route) {
    // set up $rootScope and route provider here
});
```

Comment: where are you declaring $modal as a dependency of `namespace.controllers` ? it's likely you didnt

Comment: @mpm do you mean declaring `ui.bootstrap` as a dependency?

Comment: The ui.bootstrap library is being declared in our main.js file, which is where our app is run from.

Comment: Can you you include that code as well. I think the unknown provider error is the result of ui-bootstrap not being injected correctly. Also is the bootstrap stuff included in the html

Comment: Ok, I just did. This works in every instance where we aren't referencing the LegalModalController within a directive.

Comment: look into [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) you might need to kick start the angular. You also might have to $apply in the event of a callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. The specific page within our application that this was failing on was its own module, and thus didn't have the correct bootstrap ui dependencies.  Oops >.< .